# How to write remove script from Jquery cloned div

Tags: jquery

I have tried to Make multiple identical copies of email fields through Jquery clone and also for removing of it's each cloned divs. Everything works fine but the remove script get removed the first cloned div not below of it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#addMoreEmail').on('click', function () {
        $('#emailAddMore')
            .clone()
            .appendTo("#email_fields");
    });
    $('#itsremoved').on('click', function () {
        $("#email_fields").children("div[id=email_fields]:last").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't see a remove script?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but I'd like to cite this point, per the [jQuery documentation of `.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/): *"Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead."*

Comment: This `$("#email_fields").children("div[id=email_fields]:last")` should just be `$("#email_fields")`.  If the id `email_fields` is not unique then you will get some inconsistent behavior and technically invalid html.  My hunch is you have lots of duplicate ids in your DOM (see @TylerRoper 's comment).